# Are Pym/Cross Particles used up?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man, ant-man-2015

While we don't see experimentation with Pym Particles, we do see experimentation with Cross Particles. We see Cross zap (for lack of a better term) various subjects with Cross Particles to (attempt) to cause them to shrink.

Do the usage of the Pym/Cross particles use up the particles? Do the suits supplies of particles need to be restocked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it does. Cross, at least, makes this explicit when he

> sells the suit technology to HYDRA.

He specifically points out that he's keeping the secret to the particles to himself, so any prospective buyer of the suits will need to come to him for the "fuel" that runs them.

There are also other, less obvious indications that the particles are somehow used up. In one of the early scenes with Scott, Hank can be seen "refilling" the reserve of particles that is kept in the suit.

Comment: I wasn't sure if he was just selling them unpowered suits without *any* particles (like selling them a car with an empty gas tank), or if he was giving them some particles that would need to be replaced.

Comment: The way he said it implied that they'd have to *continue* coming back to him to buy the "fuel", which only really makes sense if it gets used up.